# Lost connection to MySQL server with Mongo connector

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to power bi "ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(a) Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060".

My bi connector is on vm where my mongo server is allocated, I created a service which is running and I have no error logs but I still can't connect using powerbi. This is the mongosqld.conf I'm using

```
systemLog:
  path: '/var/log/mongosqld.log'
net:
  bindIp: '127.0.0.1'
  port: 3307
mongodb:
    net:
        uri: 'server_ip'
        ssl:
            enabled: false
        auth:
            username: user
            password: pwd
security:
  enabled: true
```

What I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Find out what mysql error 10060 means?